# Inserting data in HBASE table from HIVE Integration

Tags: hadoop, integration, hbase, hive

I am getting error in Step#5 below...any help is much appreciated.

I am following the steps given in https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/hbaseintegration.html

Step#1

```
hive> CREATE TABLE tblHbase(key int, a int, b int,c bigint)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,f:a,f:b,f:c")
TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name"="tblHbase");
```

Step#2

```
hbase(main):001:0> describe "tblHbase"
DESCRIPTION                                        ENABLED                   
 {NAME => 'tblHbase', FAMILIES => [{NAME => 'f', B true                      
 LOOMFILTER => 'NONE', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', V                           
 ERSIONS => '3', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIO                           
 NS => '0', TTL => '2147483647', BLOCKSIZE => '655                           
 36', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}]                           
 }
```

Step#3

```
hive> describe tblhive;
```

OK
id      int
a       int
b       int
c       bigint

Step#4

```
hive> select * from tblhive;
```

OK
1       101     102     103
2       201     202     203

Step#5   -- Error in inserting data into HBase table from Hive

```
hive> insert overwrite table tblHbase select id,a,b,c from tblhive;

Total MapReduce jobs = 1 Launching Job 1 out of 1 Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 
since there's no reduce operator Starting Job = job_1347311485447_0005, 
Tracking URL = <url_deleted> Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=0.0.0.0:8021
-kill job_1347311485447_0005 Hadoop job information for Stage-0: 
number of mappers: 1; 
number of reducers: 0 
2012-09-10 18:19:35,844 Stage-0 map = 0%,  reduce = 0% Ended Job = job_1347311485447_0005 with errors Error during job, obtaining debugging information... 
Examining task ID: task_1347311485447_0005_m_000000 (and more) from job job_1347311485447_0005

Task with the most failures(4): 
----- Task ID:   task_1347311485447_0005_m_000000

URL:   http://x.x.x.x:50030/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_1347311485447_0005&tipid=task_1347311485447_0005_m_000000
-----

**FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask** 
MapReduce Jobs Launched:  Job 0: Map: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 
FAIL Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

Comment: Great first post Eijaz Rasool! But try to make your questions a bit more direct though, especially the title.

Comment: When you come across mapreduce errors/failures like this follow the directions in the prompt by accessing the task log and use that log to further diagnose the problem.

Comment: please attach the partial log